# Where could mount points exist, or not exist?

Tags: linux, mount

This is a very theoretical question with no actual real-world use.

Is there a way to determine, or a list of locations, where a mount point can (not) reside?

From what I heard, and my understanding is meager at best, you can specify *any* accessible directory to mount a volume. But can you mount in `/boot/myvolume`? Is there any problem at all with mounting in `/run/shm/myvolume` (assuming you recreate the directory after every boot)??

I'm looking for a list where mounts could plausibly reside (or conversely, can never reside) without breaking expected functionality of both the volume and the OS, even if the person or program that mounted the volume is a total troll.

I'm trying not to limit to any Linux flavor, but if it matters for the argument, assume Debian, Red Hat, Arch, and/or SUSE based, in this order of preference. I think these are the most popular flavors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux, a mount point can exist at any point. Mounting things, especially bind-mounting things, at seemingly strange locations is a relatively common way to create an environment some programs might use, so I don't think /boot/myvolume strikes me as special at all. On the contrary, /boot/EFI probably is a separate mountpoint on your system.

> I'm looking for a list where mounts could plausibly reside (or conversely, can never reside) without breaking expected functionality of both the volume and the OS, even if the person or program that mounted the volume is a total troll.

That list is empty. The point of a file system is to give you a structured way to access something. If putting something in there without consequence was possible at any directory, you should probably delete that directory – nothing uses it.

If a troll has the rights to mount arbitrary stuff on your system, you've lost, and the troll owns your system. There's really no safeguards against that.

If anything, it would be reasonable to assume a user can do anything they want within the confines of their own home directory (and maybe `/run/media/[user]/`, `/var/run/user/[uid]`), risking only confusing their own processes. That's generally the point: you want to restrict a user. To which directories should they have potentially modifying access? Since they can mess up these directories to their heart's delight anyways, they should also be able to mount things there. Not gonna get any worse.

Problem is that as a normal user you *can't* mount things, usually. You go through services or setuid programs (udisks, systemd-automount, podman …) that actually run with the necessary (root) amount of privileges, and make sure they only mount things in places you, as the requesting user, has access to:

```bash
# I'm at home. Can do arbitrary stuff here.
> fallocate -l 1G ~/filesystemimage
> mkfs.xfs ~/filesystemimage

# doesn't let me mount just anywhere, but picks the directory for me
# in a place that has a SELinux context that says, hey, programs like 
# udisks can mount there (ls -Z /run/media/marcus: `system_u:object_r:mnt_t`)
# and that is named preeeeetty unambiguously so that any reasonable human or
# software author will not think of relying on any data there unless
# run as the same user
> udisksctl loop-setup -f ~/filesystemimage


# Will let me mount a remote directory in a directory I own:
> mkdir ~/mnt
> sshfs myuser@myserver.com:/data ~/mnt && echo Success || echo Faaaail
Success
# … but will straight up refuse to mount where I'm not the owner
# /opt is owned by root, not me
> sshfs myuser@myserver.com:/data /opt && echo Success || echo Faaaail
Faaaail
```

**Good news**, though, is that you *can* give a developer user / troll the ability to work with mounting stuff at the strangest places, without any affecting the rest of the filesystem. A *filesystem namespace* gives a process (or a group of processes) their own idea of what the filesystem looks like. That's the thing *containers* are built on! If you, say, installed `podman` (and your distro or yourself made the appropriate `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` entries so you can run unprivileged containers), your normal user can run something like

```bash
podman run -it --rm -v /home/user/data:/boot/fooobar:Z debian:stable
```

to their heart's delight, mounting a directory they have access to as /boot/foobar inside the container, and getting a shell process that sees that instead of what the other processes of the user see.